# DSE SOLR javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We just published a change to the schema for our DSE SOLR cluster.  We tried reloading the core on this node and it couldn't load the core.  We then drained and stopped DSE. on startup we get the following exception:

```
 INFO 23:25:52,673 Configuring index commit log for linkcurrent_search.content
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.datastax.    bdp:type=CommitLog-linkcurrent_search.content
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.JMXUtil.registerMBean(JMXUtil.java:36)
    at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.index.solr.AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.init(AbstractSolrSecondaryIndex.    java:183)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.addIndexedColumn(SecondaryIndexManager.    java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.<init>(ColumnFamilyStore.java:271)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:378)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createColumnFamilyStore(ColumnFamilyStore.java:350)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.initCf(Table.java:329)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.<init>(Table.java:272)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:109)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:87)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:276)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:351)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.init(CassandraDaemon.java:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.load(DaemonLoader.java:212)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.datastax.bdp:type=CommitLog-    linkcurrent_search.content
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(    DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(    DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(    DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor    .java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.JMXUtil.registerMBean(JMXUtil.java:32)
    ... 17 more
Cannot load daemon
```

**UPDATE**

Just tried moving the `solr.data` directory out of the way to see if the issue was there and that didn't help.

I also tried moving the commitlog directory as well, but no dice.

The node **will** start up if I disable SOLR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When upgrading to the latest DSE 3.2.x, you'll get a conflict when adding new columns/fields as the name of the class implementing the Solr secondary index changed between versions: this caused your problems above.

DSE 3.2.2 will fix this issue, but in the meantime you can follow the given steps:

1. Restart the node with Solr disabled.
2. Describe your schema via CQLSH and identify the added columns with related Cassandra secondary indexes: you'll notice class names differ from already existent indexes.
3. Drop each new index and create again with exactly the same name, but changing the class name to match the old one.
4. Restart with Solr enabled and everything should work.

Comment: If I start it up with SOLR disabled, will it not go into the Cassandra datacenter?  Also This node has vnodes disabled but the nodes in the Cassandra datacenter have vnodes enabled.  Can I safely bring it up into that datacenter and take it out without loss of data or without it taking too much of the write load?

Comment: @RussBradberry if you are using the DseSimpleSnitch, you are correct, you can't do that.  You would need to to using PropertyFileSnitch (with the same DataCenter names) so that the DC name doesn't change when you change the node type.

But, if you have other nodes, you can make the schema change from those.  It doesn't have to be made from the Solr node.